# How do I get a translucent background with opaque text?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying this method, I just put 2 divs, I style the first adding the background and making it translucent and I style the first to make it opaque:

This is the code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="opaquetext">
      This is a normal text
      on a translucent background
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
   #container {
       background-color: #ffffff;  /* the background          */
       filter:alpha(opacity=50);   /* Internet Explorer       */
       -moz-opacity:0.5;           /* Mozilla 1.6 and below   */
       opacity: 0.5;               /* newer Mozilla and CSS-3 */
    }
    #opaquetext {
       filter:alpha(opacity=100);  /* discarded */
       -moz-opacity:1.0;           /* discarded */
       opacity: 1.0;               /* discarded */
    }
```

I thought it would work but for some reason it renders the text transparent too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the backgrounds using rgba() instead of #... or rgb() where the last argument in rgba denotes the opacity of background. Opacity is for defining the opacity of whole element. Eg:

```
background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)
```

More info about this: http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/

But it may raise compatibility issues with old browsers and ie. If you want to support older browsers you should consider using transparent background image as specified in boltclock's answer.

Comment: Thanks, I give a damn about IE!

Answer (score 3):

Opacity styles affect the display of an entire element - both its background and foreground colors. The styles are also multiplied down a tree of elements. In other words, your inner `div` is simply being styled to have 100% opacity of the outer `div`. 100% of 50% opacity means it displays at the same opacity as the parent element: 50%.

There are two workarounds, neither of which require two `div`s, both of which allow you to specify `color: #000000` for your text as usual:

- Use a transparent background image
  <sup>IE does not support this before IE7</sup>
- Use `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)`
  <sup>IE does not support this before IE9, Firefox does not support this before 3.5</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Opacity inheriting is the standard behavior of all browsers. If you want the child div dis-inherited on opacity, you have two choices:

1. using absolute position in #opaquetext's style:

   ```
   #opaquetext {
       position: absolute;
       top: 10px;
       left: 10px;
       filter:alpha(opacity=100);  /* worked */
       -moz-opacity:1.0;           /* worked */
       opacity: 1.0;               /* worked */
   }
   ```
2. using photo/image software to make a background with the desired opacity, and drop opacity setting in css.

ref:

- http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/
- http://www.wickham43.supanet.com/~wickham43/tutorial/opacity.html